# Why does the doc say not to call Synchronize from the main thread?

Tags: delphi

The [delphi doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) says that we can not call `TThread.synchronize` from the main thread

> Warning: Do not call Synchronize from within the main thread. This can cause an infinite loop.

However I don't quite understand why because `TThread.synchronize` will do

```
class procedure TThread.Synchronize(ASyncRec: PSynchronizeRecord; QueueEvent: Boolean = False);
var
  SyncProc: TSyncProc;
  SyncProcPtr: PSyncProc;
begin
  if CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID then
  begin
    if Assigned(ASyncRec.FMethod) then
      ASyncRec.FMethod()
    else if Assigned(ASyncRec.FProcedure) then
      ASyncRec.FProcedure();
  end else
    ....
  end;
end;
```

As you can see if it's called from the main thread, the function will be simply executed, so where is the danger to have an infinite loop?

Comment: The instance method also calls this class method.

Comment: _A long long time ago_ the synchronize method, from older Delphi versions, would post a windows message to the main loop, based on the assumption that it is running a message pump. There the message handler would call your method pointer. If you called Synchronize on the main thead, the message pump (Application.ProcessMessages) would no longer run, causing an infinite loop (or more exactly a deadlock).

Comment: @LU RD, that question is not a duplicate of this. There is discussed a very specific situation, but here is an overall question!

Comment: @Nashev, the dupe completely covers this question. The accepted answer states that the docs are wrong for a modern version of Delphi regarding calling `Synchronize` from the main thread. If you can prove this wrong, I'm happy to see your findings.